# runtime errors in eclipse (android development) launch activity: Is there anyway to step through the source in eclipse in windows?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, classcastexception

I am trying to make an android game in eclipse (in windows).  I keep getting nulpointerexceptions, and classcastexceptions when i run my program both on the emulator and on my phone.  I have 2 classes(activities), each with their own xml layout.  the main activity runs perfectly. However when I launch the second activity with:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, Arrowscreen.class);
... 
startActivity(i);
```

I get the previously mentioned exceptions.  It always points to the source, which is not found.  **Is there anyway to step through the source in eclipse in windows?** I have looked at http://source.android.com, but there seems to be no solution for windows. I tried to follow the linux instructions from cygwin, but it doesn't seem to work(and i'd prefer to work in windows if possible).

I am still new to android development, so i may be missing something important. **Is there anything wrong with this manifest declaration?:**

```
<activity android:name=".Arrowscreen" 
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I will refrain from posting my whole code sample because it is lengthy, but i will tell you that it uses the accelerometer, gps, and a runnable for the main loop on a timer with "postDelayed".  the gps fine location permission is in the manifest also. I am stuck, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

edit: the following is the part of my code where i get the runtime exception

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.arrow);

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ArrowBackground);
        arrow1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.turningArrow);
        GPSx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        GPSy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        MGNTx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        MGNTy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        angle = 0;
        lastAngle = 0;
        arrowAngle = 0;
        mValues[0]=0; mValues[1]=0; mValues[2]=0; 

        //mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateArrow);
        mHandler.postDelayed(UpdateArrow, 400);
```

Comment: Can you post your exception stack trace..?

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
 ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2737 
 ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2753 
 ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 129 
 ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2107 
 ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 143 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4701  
 ...

Comment: Did you see this stackoverflow post?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064406/android-framework-source-level-debugging-in-eclipse.. It seems to be a duplicate. I was preparing a screen shot on how to add debugger to eclipse, but I realized I could possible reinventing the wheel.

Comment: did you make sure, that all those views you try to find are part of your arrow.xml layout?

Comment: yes, they are all there rekaszeru (now).  that was my classcastexception, but that was a newer error than my nullpointerexception, which i have been getting for days.

Comment: I had not seen that post, thank you doc_180.  I will try to follow that article.

Comment: This line: `ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2107` in your stack trace indicates that something is wrong inside your `mHandler`. Would you please share its code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question...

In Eclipse, set a breakpoint at the first line of onCreate in your Activity, and launch the app in debug mode (Run -> Degub As -> Android Application).

Two Blog posts on doing this:
1. http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html
2. http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/11/21/starting-a-debug-session-for-android-with-adt

Comment: I have tried this, but when the runtime error occurs, the information i can see is not helpful.  I cannot see the android source files.  it always occurs at the same point (shown in my comment above).

Comment: I actually just corrected the classcastException by doing this again, the error was obvious(Imagebutton != ImageView) and i should have caught it when i did this before, but i still get the null pointerException

Comment: Without your complete code available, it's difficult to help you troubleshoot it.  Looking at what code is available... Is it possible that you forgot to initialize mValues or mHandler before starting to use them in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

Check out ur "Arrowscreen" class extends "Activity" class or not, if not first do that...

I think this may help.

```
public class Arrowscreen extends Activity{
```

.....
....
}

in AndroidMainfest.xml

`<activity android:name="Arrowscreen" 
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>`